# Undefined Index - PHP(accessible before but not now)

Tags: php

i am trying to go to next page but it is currently showing "Notice: Undefined index: u...y". The values i am accessing was accessible before but now it is showing this error.. i have tried to understand the problem but all in vain.. kindly help thanks..

```
 <?php
$con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","mydb");



$titl = $_POST["u"];
$auth = $_POST["v"];
$isb = $_POST["w"];
$pub = $_POST["x"];
$keyw = $_POST["y"];

$q = "select * from mytable";   
$rs = $con->query($q);  

while($r = $rs->fetch_assoc())
{
    if($titl == $r["title"] && $auth == $r["author"] && $isb == $r["isbn"] && $pub == $r["name"] && $keyw == $r["keywords"])
    {
        echo"<html>
            <body>
            <style>
            body  
            {
                background-image: url('load1.gif');
                background-color: #cccccc;
            }
            </style>
            </body>
            </html>

            ";
            sleep(5);
             header("Location: info.php");
            exit;
    }

    else
    {
        if($check == 'notfound')
        {
        //  echo "Not Found...";
        }
    }
    echo"<br>";

  echo "</tr>";


}
echo "</table>";    
$con->close();
?>
```

Comment: Your `$_POST` does not contain `u`, `v`, `w`, `x` and `y`. Your form does not send the data. You should check that they are defined rather than always assuming they are.

Comment: My `$_POST` was working perfectly fine and was receiving values before. It contained u, v, w, x and y values but "now" it is showing the error. this is what i am mainly confused about.

Comment: Before what? Before some magic happened?

Comment: Notice that the error you get is a Notice. That mean it can be switch on or off based on your php configuration. I suspect that you turn it off before, hence it's not showing but accidentally turn it on now so it show up. Anyway, dont just count on magic, always check your code first.

Comment: The data is not sent by the form, or the error message would not be displayed. Period. You have to investigate in your code that you don't share with us to understand why the form does not send the POST data.

Comment: this is what i am confused about. after adding `sleep(5)` and `header();` the error came in an instant.

Comment: Why has this question been marked as duplicate of another one which has nothing in common?

Comment: @HassaanAhmad If you don't provide the code of the form that you submit, NOBODY on earth can help you. Unless they have magic powers (mine worked before, but not now)

Comment: i dont know either why it has been marked..
 let me provide the code from where the values are being passed..

Comment: `<form method = "POST" onSubmit = "myfun();" action = "compare.php">

<center><p style="color:white;"> Enter the "title" of the book &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp   
<input type = "text" name = "u" /> <br><br>
 Enter the "author" of the book    
<input type = "text" name = "v"  /> <br><br>
Enter the "ISBN" of the book  
<input type = "number" name = "w"  /> <br><br>
Enter the name of the "publisher" of book     
<input type = "text" name = "x"  /> <br><br>
Enter the "keywords" of the book     
<input type = "text" name = "y"  /> <br><br>
<input type = "submit" value = "submit"/></p></center>`

Comment: Please, edit your question, code in comments is unreadable...

Comment: this is the code from values are being sent. sorry it wasn't fitting in 550+ lines so had to write in that way. the procedure above is all same.

Comment: ???? It as too long, so you paste it in comments?

Comment: Hey you know what? Personally, I give up. You make no effort in debuging your own code, you don't help us helping you... Good luck. I've tried.

Comment: ` <form method = "POST" onSubmit = "myfun();" action = "compare.php">
Enter Title
<input type = "text" name = "u">
Enter author
<input type = "text" name = "v">
Enter ISBN
<input type = "number" name = "w">
Enter name
<input type = "text" name = "x">
Enter keywords
<input type = "text" name = "y">
<input type = "submit" value = "submit"/> `

Comment: sorry i am trying but i am not able to guide you well. i'll just figure out something else. well thank you for your time and sorry for wasting yours. Glad you helped :)

Answer (score 1):

It's to do with the way you're expecting `$_POST` data to be set. It's either not being set by the form submission or you're trying to access this page directly - which means you have no post data.

General practice is to only run processing like this if there is `$_POST` data set:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $titl = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'u');
    $auth = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'v');
    $isb = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'w');
    $pub = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'x');
    $keyw = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'y');

    //...rest of code
}
```

As you see above we've used [`filter_input()`](http://php.net/filter_input) to manage our POST data being sent. This is how your data will be returned/set:

- If POST field is set, will be returned.
- If the filter fails, your variable will be `false`
- If the POST is not present, your variable will be `NULL`

---

The above would be based off a form like:

```
<form action="your_page.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="u">
    ...rest of the inputs...
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

<sup>Notice the `submit` input type (`name` attribute) - along with each of the inputs having a `name` attribute.</sup>

Comment: The presence of `submit` does not mean other data will be present. Each POST data should be checked before assignment.

Comment: @Arcesilas Good point - was only addressing form submit, will update

Comment: Thanks for the edit ^^ That's the kind of situation where Frameworks are useful...

Comment: @Arcesilas Exactly right haha! Just answering to the OP's scope! Hate this vanilla kind

Comment: Or maybe provide a simple function to avoid code repetition :)

Comment: By the way, `filter_input` is not often seen, good to see it mentionned!